Is there a 1-periodic module M over a local non-Cohen Macaulay ring?
As the title states, I am looking for an example of a module $M$ (non-zero and non-free) over a non-Cohen-Macaulay local Noetherian ring $(R,\mathfrak m, k)$ where $M$ is periodic of period one. There are many classic examples over complete intersection rings—in fact, it is known that over a CI ring all modules will eventually become periodic of period one or two—but I cannot find any "hands on" examples over a non-Cohen-Macaulay ring.
I have tried to find my own examples with the help of Macaulay2, mainly using the ring $R=k[[x,y]]/(x^2,xy)$ or $R=k[[x,y,z]]/(xz,yz)$ (as I know these are not Cohen-Macaulay) and modules of the form $M=R/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$ (note: Macaulay2 cannot handle formal power series rings, so I actually used the polynomial rings, e.g., $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$). However every module I tried ended up having either finite projective dimension or the Betti numbers had Fibonacci growth.
Definition. A module $M$ is called $p$-periodic if $M\cong\Omega^pM$ where $\Omega^pM$ is a $p$th syzyzgy module of $M$ (my question is concerned with the case of $p=1$).

First a quick note, it is not true over a complete intersection that every module is eventually periodic. This property characterizes hypersurface rings, i.e., complete intersection rings of codimension at most $1$.
One cheeky way to construct examples is to take a local ring $R$ and to set $T=R[\![t]\!]/(t^2)$. We may view $R$ as a $T$-module as $R \cong T/tT$. The element $t$ is a so-called exact zero-divisor, and more to the point we have $(0:_T t)=(t)$. In this situation, the sequence
$$\cdots T \xrightarrow{\cdot t} T \xrightarrow{\cdot t} T \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0$$
is exact. In particular, $R$ is periodic of period one. One may argue in general that $\operatorname{depth}(T)=\operatorname{depth}(R)$ and $\dim(T)=\dim(R)$ in this situation, as $R$ is a so-called totally reflexive $T$-module. So we may apply this construction to any non-Cohen-Macaulay $R$, but to make things simpler and more concrete, we may take $R=k[\![x,y]\!]/(x^2,xy)$, so that $T \
\cong k[\![x,y,t]\!]/(x^2,xy,t^2)$. Then taking $M=T/tT$, Macaulay2 will confirm the relevant details for this example.

Thank you! This is a clever trick to combine $k[[t]]/(t^2)$ with $k[[x,y]]/(x^2,xy)$ like this. And yes, I was incorrect in saying all modules become eventaully periodic; I was thinking of hypersurfaces but accidentally generalized to complete intersection rings. Thank you for pointing that out.
